# Why can't we call parent constructor explicitly in child class?

Tags: java

I'm a little confused why we cannot call parent constructor inside child class constructor explicitly. If we talk about method it can be easily call inside child constructor.

```
class F {
     F() {
        System.out.println("F");
     }
}

class G extends F {

    G() {
        F();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new G();
    }
 }
```

**output**

> ```
>  G.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
>                          F();                      
>   symbol:   method F()
>   location: class G 
>   1 error
> ```

Comment: You can call parent's constructor using `super();`

Comment: i want to call explicit..

Comment: @AshwiniPandey all you can do is call super() (which is implicit in this case).

Comment: no i want to call explicit

Comment: Because a constructor cannot be called directly, like an ordinary function, you need the `new` operator.

Comment: `F();` is a method call. It does not matter even if you have a constructor with the same name. What is your goal? (or reason for calling `F` constructor explicitly) If you call `F` constructor explicitly it means you are treating it as a separate class rather than as a parent.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call the constructor of the super class, use

```
G() {
  super();
}
```

Comment: i know that............but why can't explicit

Comment: What would be the difference? As a class has only one super class, super() is as explicit as it can be.

Comment: @AshwiniPandey Because the correct syntax in Java to call the superclass' constructor is by using `super` and not by using the name of the superclass. That's just how Java was designed. Complaining that you want it differently is useless... And why do you want this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call it but you are using the wrong syntax. Use :

```
G() {
    super();
}
```

The `super()` calls the super-class constructor.

---

The constructor is called only when an object of a class is created. You cannot simply call it (*That's how the language was designed*). In your case, you could create an object which in turn would call the constructor.

```
G() {
    new F();
}
```

Comment: i know that............but why can't explicit

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: @AshwiniPandey because that's how the language was designed

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler can tell that you need to call the parent class constructor of *this* instance by the keyword `super`. If you type in the constructor name explicitly, there is no way to tell in which instance you need to call the constructor method. That is why you will need to use the keyword `new` to indicate that you need to call the constructor method in a *new* instance.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a new object you have to use the "new" keyword:

```
new F();
```